# How to print integers in a string with space separating them in python?

Tags: python

I have written the following code in python,
the fnc recieves two arguments of "Genome" and "Pattern" as a string, and whenever the pattern matches the genome, the starting index of the match is saved in a list, but I should return the result not as a list but as a string in which the indices are separated by space.
example:

## Sample Input: ATAT, GATATATGCATATACTT

## Sample Output:1 3 9

any suggestions?

```
def PatternMatching(Genome, Pattern):
    index=[]
    for i in range(len(Genome)-len(Pattern)+1):
        if Genome[i:i+len(Pattern)]==Pattern:
            index.append(i)
    return index

Genome="GATATATGCATATACTT"
Pattern="ATAT"
print(PatternMatching(Genome, Pattern))
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for e.g. *python how to print list*? You should get plenty of hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join to print the list the way you want:

```
def PatternMatching(Genome, Pattern):
    index=[]
    for i in range(len(Genome)-len(Pattern)+1):
        if Genome[i:i+len(Pattern)]==Pattern:
            index.append(i)
    return ' '.join([str(_) for _ in index]) # This is new

Genome="GATATATGCATATACTT"
Pattern="ATAT"
print(PatternMatching(Genome, Pattern))
```

Answer (score 0):

It simple as

`return ' '.join(map(str, index))`

Will work like a charm.

Comment: It will give an error because index is the list of integers

Comment: We can use the map function on str. Will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, string the index and then use the join function to join the list into a string.

```py
def PatternMatching(Genome, Pattern):
    index = []
    for i in range(len(Genome)-len(Pattern)+1):
        if Genome[i:i+len(Pattern)]==Pattern:
            index.append(str(i))
    return " ".join(index)

Genome = "GATATATGCATATACTT"
Pattern = "ATAT"
print(PatternMatching(Genome, Pattern))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the string by extracting 4 chars at a time and then compare with the needed pattern

```
>>> s = "GATATATGCATATACTT"
>>> ptrn = "ATAT"
>>> res = [i for i in range(len(s)-4) if s[i:i+4] == ptrn]
>>> out = ' '.join(map(str, res))
>>> out
'1 3 9'
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, you can just use the *iterator unpacking operator `*`*:

```
print(*PatternMatching(Genome, Pattern))
```

Comment: This is amazing, I cannot belive how short and elegant this solution is. Thank you.